# How to Add Xcode project to Github repository from windows environment

Tags: xcode, windows, github

After seeing title of my question you might think like this kind of question is already been asked before. However this is not duplicate, read below to know.

I am developing IOS application. Whenever I get time I work on that every time I use either library's PC or friend's MacBook to developing or making changes in my existing project and then I compress the project and upload it to my Google drive.

I would like to add my Xcode project to Github. I know how to do it from MacBook though. I am looking for way to push my Xcode project from windows environment. As I am poor fellow and can not afford MacBook at the moment.

or

If is there any way I can push my project to same repo on Github from different MacBook every time. As I mentioned before I am using public library to work on my IOS app it is not possible that I can be able to use same Apple PC every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make in windows console -

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/UserExample/ExampleProject
git push -u origin --all
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this worked in my case. Up voted

Answer (score 1):

There is a variety of ways to use GIT within Windows. Github is just a GIT repository cloud service. You can fetch, push, pull command line, after installing GIT on your Windows machine and then CD changing directory to your repository (where the source code is) on your Windows hard drive.

Since you are new to GIT and Github, use the very user friendly Github tool:

[Github Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/)

You will be able to use use the existing repository on your Windows hard drive, or if it gets confusing via the Github Desktop to "connect" an existing local repository to the Github repository (https:www.github/myrep). Then just backup your working project to a backup folder and clone the Github repo you are using.